# Silent push notification not working in ios 13

Tags: ios

Silent notification is not working in iPad 13 OS. But, in 12.4 OS it is working fine.

This is the payload I send from my server

```
{
    "aps": {
       "content-available" : "1"
    },
  "BuildingId":13,
 "NotificationTypeId":214,
 "CustomerName":"Test",
 "Amount":"6778",
 "CustomerID":32752,
"Environment":"TEST",
 "Title":""
}
```

Any wonder why this happens?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi, please try to post code as text rather than images, it will help people to review it! https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @Kalaimathi did you got it work?

Answer (score 2):

Adding "apns-push-type" header field solved the issue. Please note this is a APNS POST request header field, not a new key in push JSON.

Answer (score 2):

"apns-push-type" is Required when delivering notifications to devices running iOS 13 and later, or watchOS 6 and later. Ignored on earlier system versions. [Apple document APNS Silent push notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns).

Answer (score 0):

try this from postman. its work for me

```
{ 
"to":"token", 
    "content_available":true,
    "mutable_content": true,
    "data": {
        "message": "Offer!",
        "urlImageString":"https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg",
    }
}
```