# Background notifications broken in iOS 13+

Tags: ios, amazon-sns, ios13, xcode11, usernotifications

Has anyone found a solution to broken background (silent) notifications (with `content-available = 1`) on iOS 13? These notifications continue to be received normally on iOS 12.

Setting `apns-push-type = 'background'` and `apns-priority = 5` as suggested in the WWDC presentation does not seem to fix the issue.
Seems these headers not obligatory anyway - Apple says [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns?language=objc) that:

> The background push type is required on watchOS 6 and later. It is
>   recommended on macOS, iOS, tvOS, and iPadOS.

Indeed they haven't even updated their [page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app?language=objc) on "Pushing Background Updates to Your App" to mention these new headers.

I'm using AWS SNS. XCode Version 11.1. iOS 13.1.2.

And here is the payload I'm using (PHP):

```
$apnspayload = array('aps' => array('content-available' => 1,
                                    'apns-push-type' => 'background',
                                    'apns-priority' => 5,
                                    'userid' => $userid,
                                    'category' => 'SILENT_TYPE'));
```

**UPDATE**: Still broken with XCode Version 11.2 beta 2 and iOS 13.2 beta 2.

**UPDATE 2**: iOS version 13.1.3 fixes this issue. Not Amazon's fault.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58111255/silent-push-notification-not-working-in-ios-13

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57578083/is-aws-sns-adding-apns-push-type-apns-priority-to-its-ios-push-notification-he

Comment: Thanks Matt. Does that mean that AWS SNS is not handling this correctly?

Comment: Apparently now they are. But the point is to consolidate related questions for future reference.

Comment: Well, if AWS SNS has changed something on their end, it hasn't fixed things on my end. Works on iOS12 but not iOS13. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS version 13.1.3 fixes this issue. Not Amazon's fault.

Comment: do apple mention about the fix in release notes